# The service blocks its activity when the calling form goes in the background

Tags: android, service, android-8.0-oreo

I have developed a travel app (api 25), the app uses the phone's location to calculate speed (and other parameters).
The position is taken by the service that takes care of printing (and saving on a db) the various parameters.
I have a problem with the management of services on android oreo, the service blocks its activity when the calling form goes in the background.
The application works perfectly on android-n, but unfortunately on android-o I have this problem.

part of the calling form is this:

```
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        LocationUpdatesService.LocalBinder binder = (LocationUpdatesService.LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mService = null;
        mBound = false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, LocationUpdatesService.class);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
    }
    bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }

    start_stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

            if (start_stop.getText().toString() == "start") {
                //chiedo aggiornamenti
                requestLocationUpdatesON();

                start_stop.setText("stop");
            }
            else {
                requestLocationUpdatesOFF();
            }
        }
    });

    mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);

}

public void requestLocationUpdatesOFF(){
    mService.removeLocationUpdates();
    //mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
}
public void requestLocationUpdatesON(){

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            //Location Permission already granted
            //mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
            mService.requestLocationUpdates();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //Request Location Permission
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }
    else {
        //mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
        mService.requestLocationUpdates();
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(3129999);
    unbindService(mServiceConnection);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

the service:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate() {

    //wake-lock per impedire la chiusura dell'app in sleepmode
    mPM = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWL = mPM.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,
            "MyWakelockTag");
    mWL.acquire(10000);
    Log.i("MyWakeLockTag", "onCreate");


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel1 = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_1_ID,
                "Channel 1",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN
        );
        channel1.setDescription("This is Channel 1");
        channel1.setSound(null,null);
        channel1.enableLights(false);
        channel1.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        channel1.enableVibration(false);

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);
    }
}

public void requestLocationUpdates() {

    //sendNotification();

    if(!primaVoltaCronometro){
        resumeCronometro();
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        sendNotificationOreo();
    }
    else {
        sendNotification();

    }
    Log.i("Servizio", "Requesting location updates");
    //Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, true);
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationUpdatesService.class));
    try {
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
        //Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, false);
        Log.e("Servizio", "Lost location permission. Could not request updates. " + unlikely);
    }
}

public void sendNotificationOreo() {

    //mi serve per far aprire il MapsActivity al click della notifica
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.color.transparent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setContentIntent(intent)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContent(contentView)
            .build();

    if(primaVoltaCronometro) {
        startForeground(1,notification);

        long BasePerIcronometri = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

        cronometroInvisibile.setBase(BasePerIcronometri);
        contentView.setChronometer(R.id.chronometerNot, BasePerIcronometri, "\uD83C\uDFC3%s\uD83D\uDCA8", true);
        cronometroInvisibile.start();
        primaVoltaCronometro=false;
    }
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mWL.release();
    Log.i("MyWakeLockTag", "onCreate");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

I know that android oreo limits the service a lot, I hope I can help someone with a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

I remember this when I was reading "Guide to background processing" on developers guide

> Android 8.0 (API level 26) further limited background behavior, such
>   as getting location in the background and releasing cached wakelocks.

**src**: https://developer.android.com/guide/background/ 
this is not solution but hope it's gonna help ...